# 질문와 의문 차이점 difference

Tags: difference, spoken-korean

Could you please explain the difference between these two words? Sometimes I see 의문, an this confuses me a bit, cause in most cases 질문/물음 are used.

안녕하세요!

질문이라는 말 더 자주 들었지만 가끔 인터뷰를 보면 의문라는 말을 들어요. 
질문과 의문이라는 말의 차이점은 뭐예요?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**질문** It is an act of asking someone else.

**의문** This means a question in my head.

---

Example:

남대문이 어떻게 만들어졌는지 제임스에게 질문을 했다.
(Asking someone.)

남대문이 어떻게 만들어졌는지 의문을 갖게 되었다.
(Question in my head.)

Answer (score 0):

- `의문 (疑問)` means `doubt` or `being doubtful`, and `질문 (質問)` means `asking`.
- `의문 (疑問)` is a thing you **get**, `질문 (質問)` is a thing you **do**.
- Both are nouns.
- Verb `(……을/를) 의문(疑問)하다` means `to be doubtful (about ……)`, verb `질문(質問)하다` means `to ask`.

> **의문**이 들면, **질문**하라.
>
> If you're in **doubt**, **ask**.